# Bash Scripting Multiplication table

Tags: bash, multiplication

Hello I am wondering if anyone can help me :
I try to make a multiplication table for my daughter, I don't know how to make it. This is how I want to look : 
1 x 1 = ? answer 
if the answer is true then go to the next one
1 x 2 = ?
but if the answer is false then ask again 1 x 1 = ?
until the answer is Correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Multiplication table 

echo " --== Multiplication Table ==-- "
sleep 2
echo " Lesson 1"
sleep 1
echo ""


echo -n "1 x 1 = ? " ; read opt
if [ "$opt" = 1 ] 
then
echo "Correct!"
else 
echo "Wrong!"
fi

sleep 1 
echo ""
echo -n "1 x 2 = ? " ; read opt
if [ "$opt" = 2 ] 
then
echo "Correct!"
else 
echo "Wrong!"
fi
```

After the exercise is done until 10. Then show a result of how many correct answers has and how many Wrong.
Example: 
Lesson 1 is finish you have 9 correct answers and 1 wrong answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Multiplication table

echo " --== Multiplication Table ==-- "
sleep 2
echo " Lesson $1"
sleep 1
echo ""

wrong=0
correct=0
for i in {1..10}
do
    while true
    do
        echo -n "$1 x $i = ? " ; read opt
        if [ $opt = $(( $1 * $i )) ]
        then
            (( correct++ ))
            echo "Correct!"
            break
        else
            (( wrong++ ))
            echo "Wrong!"
        fi
    done
done

echo "Lesson $1 is finish you have $correct correct answers and $wrong wrong answer!"
```

You can run it with different params for any base. Such as `./script 5` for multiplication with 5.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't do what I want. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I made it. This is how I want to look like and work

```
#!/bin/bash
# Multiplication table

    echo " --== Multiplication Table ==-- "
    sleep 2
    echo " Lesson 1"
    sleep 1
    echo ""

        while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 1 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 1 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 2 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 2 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 3 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 3 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 4 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 4 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 5 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 5 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 6 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 6 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done


     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 7 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 7 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 8 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 8 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 9 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 9 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done

     while true
        do
            echo -n "1 x 10 = ? " ; read opt
            if [ $opt = 10 ]
            then
                (( correct++ ))
                echo "Correct!"
                break
            else
                (( wrong++ ))
                echo "Wrong!"
            fi
        done
    echo "Lesson 1 is finish you have $correct correct answers and $wrong wrong answer!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#######multiplication table#########
INPUT_NUMBER=$1

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "please enter at least 1 number"
exit 1
fi

if [[ ! ${INPUT_NUMBER} =~ [[:digit:]] ]];then
    echo "Incorrect usage, wrong type args"
    echo "Usage is $0 <number>"
 exit 1
fi

for i in {1..10}
do 
    echo "${INPUT_NUMBER} * ${i} = $((${INPUT_NUMBER} * ${i}))"
done
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.